# Justifying Interchange of Integral

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, adjoint-operators, pseudo-differential-operators

I am trying to show that if $P$ is a pseudo-differential operator with symbol given by $p(x,\xi)$ i.e. the operator $$P:\mathcal S\rightarrow  \mathcal S$$ defined by $$Pf(x)=\int_{\mathbb R^n}e^{ix\cdot \xi}p(x,\xi)\hat f(\xi )d\xi $$ then the formal adjoint of $P$ denoted by $P^*$ is also a pseudo-differential operator and I shall also calculate its asymptotic expansion.
Here's how I approached. Let $f,g\in \mathcal S$. Then we see that $$\langle Pf,g \rangle =\int _{\mathbb R^n} e^{ix\cdot \xi}p(x,\xi)\hat f (\xi)\bar g(x)d\xi dx = \int _{\mathbb R^n}\int _{\mathbb R^n}\int _{\mathbb R^n}e^{i(x-y)\cdot \xi}p(x,\xi)f(y)\bar g(x)dyd\xi dx$$    I want to write this last integral as $\displaystyle{\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(y)\left (\int _{\mathbb R^n}\int _{\mathbb R^n}e^{i(x-y)\cdot \xi}p(x,\xi)\bar g(x)dxd\xi  \right )dy}$ but I cannot justify this step. Any help/hint would be appreciated.

Note: You may assume my symbols have compact $x$-support.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{S}$ ?

Comment: $\mathcal S=\mathcal S(\mathbb R^n)$ is the space of Schwartz class functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space

Comment: Okay, so what prevents you to use Fubini's theorem ?

Comment: How do you control the $\xi$ integral ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot justify this for a general $p$. For example, if $p$ is a symbol of order 0, the quantity
\begin{equation}
\int _{\mathbb R^n}\int _{\mathbb R^n}\int _{\mathbb R^n}e^{i(x-y)\cdot \xi}p(x,\xi)f(y)\bar g(x)dyd\xi dx 
\end{equation}
is not well defined. You can make your calculation work easily if (for example) $p \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^d)$, and find the expression of $p^\ast$ in this case. For a more general $p$, you should read a course of microlocal analysis : you will be able to use the notion of oscillatory integral to justify properly those kinds of calculations.